# What is the unit of measurement for the velocity display?

Tags: evochron-mercenary

I am trying to get a sense of distance and scale of the universe and of the structures on the planets, but all I have is a single velocity display with a number on it.  What is the unit of measurement of velocity for the number being displayed?  Is it meters/second?  miles/hour?  furlongs per fortnight?

Comment: What about knots per nanosecond?

Comment: @Raven I will only accept knots if its either granny knots or monkey fists knots per nanosecond and not that silly nautical term :P

Comment: Or... knautical, as case may be.